# Logon script to ask question then launch vpn connection

Tags: vbscript

I am looking to create a logon script with the following logic/requirements.

On logon pop up message:  Do you wish to connect to the VPN, Yes/NO?

If yes launch existing VPN connection box, end user then can enter creds or hit connect if creds are already saved.

If no, box disappears.

I started with this:

```
x=msgbox("Corporate VPN Connection", 4+32, "You must connect to the VPN when not physically in the office.  Do you wish to connect to the VPN now?")
```

Which shows the box OK, but I need further guidance on how to link the click of the buttons to the yes/no functions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get started by this code :

```
Option Explicit
Dim Title,Message,Answer_Question

Title = "Corporate VPN Connection"
Message = "You must connect to the VPN when not physically in the office. Do you wish to connect to the VPN now ?"
Answer_Question = Msgbox(Message,VbQuestion+vbYesNo,Title)

If Answer_Question = vbYes Then 
    Wscript.echo "We are starting The VPN Connection"
Else 
' We quit the script
    Wscript.Quit
End If
```